# How to use One view with Multiple Guards Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-6, laravel-7, laravel-views

I have multiple guards in my system

```
Admin
User
```

Admin and User both can add the Organizations details but they have different template layout. What i'm doing now i create views of each guard like this

```
views
  user
    organizations
       index.blade.php
       _form.blade.php
       create.blade.php
       edit.blade.php
  admin
    organizations
       index.blade.php
       _form.blade.php
       create.blade.php
       edit.blade.php
```

Now i want to create one views which can be used by multiple guards with different layouts

```
views
   organizations
      index.blade.php
      _form.blade.php
      create.blade.php
      edit.blade.php
```

Comment: I don’t know if I understand you correctly, but are you trying to have a view that displays different information depending on whether the user has a user role or an admin role?

Comment: Yes one view displays same information but different template based on the guards not roles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Laravel Blade Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade):

If needed, you may specify the authentication guard that should be checked when using the @auth and @guest directives:

```
@auth('admin')
    // The user is authenticated...
@endauth

@guest('admin')
    // The user is not authenticated...
@endguest
```

Comment: current i'm doing this but i'm worried about the performance of checking current user logged guard every time visit the page. Is there another way of doing this?

Comment: If that is what you are doing, then I'd say you are good. This should not be impacting performance.